# Average items in two rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, multiple-columns, rows

I have the following, which averages up to E, but I have up to QE to average. How can I do this without writing in every letter?

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A2,B1:B2,C1:C2,D1:D2,E1:E2)
```

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AVERAGE(A1:EQ2)
```

That should work?

EDIT:

I think what your really asking is how to get the average of the two above cells in row 3 - which is just pasting `=AVERAGE(A1:A2)` in A3 then dragging it to the end of your data.

What you had, `=AVERAGE(A1:A2,B1:B2,C1:C2,D1:D2,E1:E2)` was equivalent to =AVERAGE(A1:E2), it was averaging all the data in the ranges you gave it, which were continuous.

EDIT, Again:

Rereading I think Jeeped's comment is right and he wants a rolling average up to the column, which is `=average($a1:a2)` drug over.

Comment: That doesn't work. For some reason, it returns a lower number under each column of two numbers, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: What I posted will just get the average of all the numbers in the selection. Dragging it is moving that selection and excluding data, which is why it's getting smaller.  Sounds like you want each value in row 3 to be the average of the two above it.  I'll update the answer for that.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to this and I've been looking for how to do this.

Comment: If your update doesn't nail it, I suspect it may be `=average($a1:a2)` dragged right.

Comment: @Jeeped may be right too.  Theirs is making each value in row 3 be the values from the first two rows up to the column you're in.

Comment: `=average($a1:a2)` did not work. The answer without the dollar sign works.